# Use variables inside a postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, variables, triggers

i really need help. I'm doing a trigger in postgreSQL and i have this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION precioCompra() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $PrecioCompra$

DECLARE
valorProducto numeric;
valorOferta numeric;
valorPack numeric;
valorServicio numeric;
precioIVA numeric;
precioSinIVA numeric;
fila integer;
BEGIN

fila := new."numeroCompra";

SELECT SUM("precioIVA"*"cantidad") as valor
FROM "Producto", (select "codigoProducto", "cantidad" 
FROM "IncluyeProducto" WHERE "IncluyeProducto"."numeroCompra" = fila) as producto
    where producto."codigoProducto" = "Producto"."codigoProducto" into valorProducto;
IF valorProducto IS NULL then
    valorProducto := 0;
END IF;

select SUM("precioIVA"*"cantidad") as valor
FROM "Oferta", (select "codigoProducto", "cantidad" 
FROM "IncluyeOferta" WHERE "IncluyeOferta"."numeroCompra" = fila) as oferta
    where oferta."codigoProducto" = "Oferta"."codigoProducto" into valorOferta; 

IF valorOferta IS NULL then
    valorOferta := 0;
END IF;

select SUM("precioIVA"*"cantidad") as valor
FROM "Servicio", (select "codigoServicio", "cantidad" 
FROM "IncluyeServicio" WHERE "IncluyeServicio"."numeroCompra" = fila) as servicio
    where servicio."codigoServicio" = "Servicio"."codigoServicio" into valorServicio;

IF valorServicio IS NULL then
    valorServicio := 0;
END IF;

select SUM("precioIVA"*"cantidad") as valor
FROM "Pack", (select "codigoPack", "cantidad" 
FROM "IncluyePack" WHERE "IncluyePack"."numeroCompra" = fila) as pack
    where pack."codigoPack" = "Pack"."codigoPack" into valorPack; 

IF valorPack IS NULL then
    valorPack := 0;
END IF;

RAISE NOTICE 'El valor de Pack es % ',valorPack;

precioIVA := valorProducto + valorPack + valorServicio + valorOferta;
precioSinIVA := precioIVA / 1.21;
new."importeIVA" := precioIVA;
new."importeSinIVA" := precioSinIVA;
RETURN NEW; 
END;

$PrecioCompra$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER PrecioCompra After Insert ON "Compra" 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE precioCompra();
```

If i use a number instead of variable fila (inside the query) it prints the right value of everything, but then i look in the "Compra" table and it doesn't work. It doesn't update the value of precioIVA and precioSinIVA. (Last rows in the procedure)

If i use the variable fila like in the code, the result of the queries is null.

It's killing me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> It doesn't update the value of precioIVA and precioSinIVA
>   And your code is: `CREATE TRIGGER PrecioCompra After Insert ON "Compra"` 
>   If you want this trigger to fire on updates, you should use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PrecioCompra After Insert or Update ON "Compra"
```